# Can i build an application in python that will auto populate docusign fields from a google sheet?

Tags: python, html, docusignapi

I use docusign every day and have set up a google sheet that auto populates the email subject and body.

I'm still having to copy and paste this data into the 'email subject' & 'email message'. See screenshot example.

Is there a way i can reduce this process to the click of a button?

[image]

Comment: Answered below. If it was helpful, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Here's are two rough flows that would be helpful to pursue.

1. You could make use of the [Google Apps Script](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/api-tutorial-for-beginners/) to push data directly to DocuSign. Downside here is that you'd be writing the code in JavaScript.
2. You can write a short python app yourself, which uses the Google Sheets API (via python sdk) to retrieve your data, then pass along the appropriate info to the DocuSign eSignature API (via python sdk).

In either case, once you have access to the data you wish to forward to DocuSign, you will want to first [authenticate your account](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) to make API requests on your behalf.

Then you can make a request like this:

POST /envelopes

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign these documents",
    "emailBlurb": "Thank you for subscribing. Click the link to sign",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "JVBER...iUlRU9GCg==",
            "name": "Test Doc",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentId": "1"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Test User",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "numberTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "PO #",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "xPosition": "200",
                            "yPosition": "200",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, i'm familiar with GS and trying to learn PY as well. This has been super helpful thank you!